# Recursively search and replace the contents of multiple file types

Tags: find, regex, sed

I have thousands of web files(*.php, *.htm, *.html, etc) that contain an absolute path(http://site.com/sites/etc). I need to scan a directory and all subdirectories for the various file types and within those files, modify my absolute path to a relative one of my choosing and then leave the rest of the file as is. It must not change the path of any other absolute URLs though.

I've checked the similar questions already posted on the matter but none seem to address this directly. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -type f -print | 
  xargs sed -i.bak 's#http://site.com/sites/etc#something else#g'
```

Comment: I think that will do it. There is a test flag for sed, right?

Comment: Since `-i.bak` will create the backups in their current web accessible location, could I suggest that you move them after the operation is complete? You probably want to avoid an potential for exposing your server side bits as plain text.

Comment: @AaronCopley That's a good point. Luckily, this is just the data migration. None of the externally routable IPs are pointing to this site yet.